# Pandas: How to fill missing values in a large dataset?

Tags: python, pandas, performance, data-science

I do have a large dataset (around 8 million rows x 25 columns) in Pandas and I am struggling to do one operation in a performant manner.

Here is how my dataset looks like:

```
                   temp   size
location_id hours             
135         78     12.0  100.0
            79      NaN    NaN
            80      NaN    NaN
            81     15.0  112.0
            82      NaN    NaN
            83      NaN    NaN
            84     14.0   22.0
```

- I have a multi-index on [location_id, hours]. I have around 60k locations and 140 hours for each location (making up the 8 million rows).
- The rest of the data is numeric (float). I have only included 2 columns here, normally there are around 20 columns.
- What I am willing to do is to fill those `NaN` values by using the values around it. Basically, the value of hour `79` will be derived from the values of `78` and `81`. For this example, the `temp` value of `79` will be `13.0` (basic extrapolation).
- I always know that only the `78, 81, 84 (multiples of 3)` hours will be filled and the rest will have `NaN`. That will always be the case. This is true for hours between `78-120`.
- With these in mind, I have implemented the following algorithm in Pandas:

```
df_relevant_data = df.loc[(df.index.get_level_values(1) >= 78) & (df.index.get_level_values(1) <= 120), :]

for location_id, data_of_location_id in df_relevant_data.groupby("location_id"):

        for hour in range(81, 123, 3):

            top_hour_data = data_of_location_id.loc[(location_id, hour), ['temp', 'size']] # e.g. 81
            bottom_hour_data = data_of_location_id.loc[(location_id, (hour - 3)), ['temp', 'size']] # e.g. 78

            difference = top_hour_data.values - bottom_hour_data.values
            bottom_bump = difference * (1/3) # amount to add to calculate the 79th hour
            top_bump = difference * (2/3) # amount to add to calculate the 80th hour

            df.loc[(location_id, (hour - 2)), ['temp', 'size']] = bottom_hour_data.values + bottom_bump
            df.loc[(location_id, (hour - 1)), ['temp', 'size']] = bottom_hour_data.values + top_bump
```

- This works really well functionally, however the performance is horrible. It is taking at least 10 minutes on my dataset and that is currently not acceptable.
- Is there a better/faster way to implement this? I am actually working only on a slice of the whole data (only hours between 78-120) so I would really expect it to work much faster.

Comment: Have you tried playing around with [`interpolate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html), as in `df.interpolate()`?

Comment: @HenryYik You are a life saver. With `interpolate()`, it took less than 20 seconds for the whole data ste. Thank you so much. Can you post this as an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: Sure, answer added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for [`interpolate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html):

```
print (df.interpolate())

                        temp   size
location_id hours
135         78     12.000000  100.0
            79     13.000000  104.0
            80     14.000000  108.0
            81     15.000000  112.0
            82     14.666667   82.0
            83     14.333333   52.0
            84     14.000000   22.0
```